# How to config tmux to move window lists from default bottom to top?

Tags: tmux

I want to move window lists from bottom to top.

Application's status bar looks weird to me if it was above tmux's window list.

Any hints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this [answer on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33531/6761). If you build from SVN you can set the status bar on top with:

```
set-option -g status-position top
```

This will be included in `tmux 1.7`

Comment: it doesn't work, error message showed no option named status-position. btw, i am using deb package from ubuntu mirror.

Comment: You have to [build the current version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tmux/develop)...

Comment: Another question, latest verson on sourceforge was 1.6, where can i get source code of version 1.7? this is the url i download form [tmux url](https://tmux.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tmux)

Comment: OK, i found it from [here](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/tmux/1.7~svn2691-1), now it works, thank you again. : P